# git: merge of csv files

Tags: git

I have a CSV file

```
 :> file save.dat
 save.dat: CSV text
```

This is made of lines like this:

```
 2022-12-31,08:36,meer,CLOSE_WRITE|CLOSE,/hd2/projects/inv,900.Oliver.odt
```

My local file has a line that differs from the MASTER version by a single line that is guaranteed unique through the algorithm that generates the lines.

Git refuses to merge the files as I see it often does well with source code: includes a marker in the file with a version identifier.

Why is git not merging this file in that way. What can I do to force the merge? In the current situation I have to perform the merge manually through a busy process.

Comment: Does the file have an [attribute specifying it can't be merged or binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11162362/836748)?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco It was writable only by my user who created the file. My user is also the checkout id (stephen@gitserver) . I have made it universally writeable (This is a single user system) and so far no repetition of the issue despite my simple attempts to replicate it. There are some strange effects however. For another question.

Comment: That's not at all what I was linking to. `git` attributes != filesystem attributes.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco O I see. I completely missed that it was a link. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comment by @Aaron D.Marasco I added the `.gitattributes` file  to the project root directory.

The problematic file is named `save.dat` so the attributes file wants this

```
 *.dat text
```